# Removing Circular Dependency in Native android

Tags: android, c, shared-libraries, native, circular-dependency

I have a file A.c and another file B.c, There is a function func1 in A.c which is defined in B.c and a function func2 in B.c which is defined in A.c. Now when I am trying to build the separate so library with A.c and B.c, then the compiler throws circular dependency error at linking time.
So is there any way so that I can link the two libraries together? Or I can make the linking delayed i.e libA.so will not link until libB.so is compiled.

For Example :-

File *A.h* :-

```
void func1();
```

File *A.c*

```
void func1()
{
   printf ("Hello A");
}

void other_function()
{
   func2();
}
```

File *B.h*

```
void func2();
```

File *B.c*

```
void func2()
{
  printf("Hello B");
}

void other_function ()
{
    func1();
}
```

Comment: do you use declaration in header files? Or is the call to func1 in func2 and does func2 call func1? Can you give a short source code example as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please check. And let me know if you have any doubt @KamiKaze

Comment: Try including both A.h and B.h in A.c and B.c.

Comment: Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/625801/7095889) answer.

Comment: what are the includes?

Answer (score -1):

We can achieve this kind of linking by using static library instead of shared library. I used that and it worked.